# Hardware details of the new RAM not having correct values

Tags: linux, laptop, hardware-detection

I have a thinkpad X260 laptop in which I run both windows and linux manjaro.

This laptop comes with only one RAM slot and had 4gb by default. Got the ram upgraded to 8gb at an authorized local dealer of lenovo - he replaced the older one with a new ram of Transcend company.

But I have a concern about this upgrade. When I run `sudo dmidecode --type 17 | more` command in linux after this upgrade, the fields **Manufacturer** and **Serial number** do not have legit values.

I have given the output of dmidecode command for before and after this upgrade for comparison.

**Before RAM upgrade** [for the 4gb ram]

```
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0008
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Samsung       <<<<<<< Check this
    Serial Number: 99362A80     <<<<<<< Check this
    Asset Tag: None
    Part Number: M471A5143EB0-CPB   
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
```

**After RAM upgrade** [removing 4gb and putting the new 8gb Transcend RAM]

```
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0008
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 0000        <<<<<<<< See this
    Serial Number: 00000000   <<<<<<<< See this
    Asset Tag: None
    Part Number: V01D4SF8GB5285282400
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
```

Is this fine? Or should I be worried about the authenticity of the new RAM?

Please do advice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the RAM works it is fine. Apparently Transcend does not have it's own fab, so it buys component chips from other suppliers - thus it's more generic and less likely to be branded.

You should run a memory test if you have any concerns. (Burn a bootable pendrive with memtest86 , fire it up and leave it - at least overnight, - but longer is better)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Glad to know that it is not an immediate point of concern. Will run the tests as you suggested in sometime.